# Why isn't SMB Direct working over RDMA?

Tags: powershell, server-message-block, windows-server-2019, mellanox, rdma

In a Windows lab environment, I'm trying to test performance of SMB Direct using Mellanox RDMA adapters with global pause.  I wanted to test first with Global Pause for simplicity before switching to PFC.  I think I've set up everything correctly, but SMB Direct is not being used.  I can tell because RDMA performance counters remain at zero and actual bandwidth is displayed in Task Manager.

I verified RDMA connectivity using `nd_write_bw` in both directions.

Server: Win2019 Datacenter with Mellanox ConnectX-5 100GbE
Client: Win10 Pro for Workstations with Mellanox ConnectX-4 Lx 25GbE
Both machines have WinOF2 2.40.50000 driver with Flow Control Rx/Tx enabled
The switch has global pause enabled and PFC disabled
I have enabled SMB Direct feature on the client.

On the client, `Get-SmbMultichannelConnection` is empty.  What could be causing this?

Here is the server configuration:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetOffloadGlobalSetting | Select NetworkDirect

NetworkDirect
-------------
      Enabled

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapterRDMA fastnet

Name                      InterfaceDescription                     Enabled     PFC        ETS
----                      --------------------                     -------     ---        ---
fastnet                   Mellanox ConnectX-5 Adapter              True        False      False


PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo fastnet

Name                           Segment Bus Device Function Slot NumaNode PcieLinkSpeed PcieLinkWidth Version
----                           ------- --- ------ -------- ---- -------- ------------- ------------- -------
fastnet                              0 216      0        0    2        1      8.0 GT/s            16 1.1

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableMultichannel

EnableMultichannel
------------------
              True

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SmbServerNetworkInterface

Scope Name Interface Index RSS Capable RDMA Capable Speed    IpAddress
---------- --------------- ----------- ------------ -----    ---------
*          6               True        False        1 Gbps   192.168.3.55
*          4               True        True         100 Gbps 192.168.10.55

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat.exe -xan | ? {$_ -match "445"}
  Kernel       4 Listener       192.168.10.55:445      NA                     0
```

And here is the client configuration:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbClientConfiguration | Select EnableMultichannel

EnableMultichannel
------------------
              True

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbClientNetworkInterface

Interface Index RSS Capable RDMA Capable Speed   IpAddresses                                  Friendly Name
--------------- ----------- ------------ -----   -----------                                  -------------
6               True        True         40 Gbps {fe80::d1ac:ef30:6f70:a1bc, 169.254.161.188} chelsio40
4               True        True         25 Gbps {192.168.10.53}                              mlnx25
8               True        False        1 Gbps  {fe80::f912:79b2:e851:3cb4, 192.168.3.53}    housenet

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbConnection

ServerName    ShareName UserName              Credential            Dialect NumOpens
----------    --------- --------              ----------            ------- --------
192.168.10.55 NVMe      DESKTOP-K69SD7G\admin DESKTOP-K69SD7G\admin 3.1.1   5


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbMultichannelConnection
PS C:\Windows\system32> netstat.exe -xan | ? {$_ -match "445"}
PS C:\Windows\system32> netstat.exe -an | ? {$_ -match "445"}
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.10.53:58881    192.168.10.55:445      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Switch: Mellanox SN2100
PFC is enabled on the switch, so I disabled it for these specific ports and enabled Global Pause

```
int eth 1/10-1/12 flowcontrol send on force
int eth 1/10-1/12 flowcontrol receive on force
int eth 1/10-1/12 dcb priority mode off force
```